# Okhttp always return error 404 but work perfectly in chrome on windows

Tags: android, kotlin, http-status-code-404, okhttp

Hi I use okhttp it works fine but for this [url](https://www.pstream.net/h/480/eyJpdiI6IlFCUS9FNDFwOW9UTFJYU3BPaXJpb1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZWQ3RXlYUnhwa2F3QWZ6TDd1a0dYQT09IiwibWFjIjoiNGM0YTk5NzRlMDAwMTEwYjY5ZTRmYWIwYzk0YTMzMmQ1MWQzOTYxZWI0M2EyMGJhNTg5YTgzYzA1ODExMGE4MyJ9.m3u8?expires=1615181186&signature=259a1b8921d79010a91b70d76dae20e4897d3cd32c4effc5fb416cff2119b9e8) okhttp always return 404 response

I try this link on  chrome on windows and it works perfecty and Method used is GET

```
val client = OkHttpClient()
val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback{
   override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {}
   override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {}
   })
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reproducing this in curl.  Copy as Curl and see if that works.  It likely relies on being logged in with session auth.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/replay-a-network-request-in-curl

If you confirm that works, try those same headers in a request in OkHttp.  Then work out if there is a clean API to hit.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although it might work for you, I personally get a 404 error when using Chrome, so I think this might be a server side issue and not anything related to your code.